# ptyHost was unable to resolve shell environment Error

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

So I've been having a lot of issues with VS Code Remote-SSH. I just started using it in September, previously using Atom, and this month I've been running into a ton of issues. I wound up uninstalling VS Code twice to try and resolve it, as well as delete the .vscode-server folder in the home directory on my linux machine.

Now, I can't even use VS Code to ssh into my environment. It keeps giving this error. This is from the .vscode-server/.log file.

```
*
* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
* as described in the license https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/license
*

Extension host agent listening on 35175

[02:21:35] Extension host agent started.
[02:21:46] No ptyHost heartbeat after 6 seconds
[02:21:47] ptyHost was unable to resolve shell environment Error: Unable to resolve your shell environment in a reasonable time. Please review your shell configuration.
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/kbree/.vscode-server/bin/ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247/out/vs/server/remoteExtensionHostAgent.js:85:55472)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

Comment: Remote-ssh will not work if the login shell is not the bash shell (or zsh maybe). Aren't you using a shell other than bash?

Comment: I was using a Bash shell. However, I got it to work, actually. I had to reboot the server to do it. Not exactly sure why.

For future reference, I ran "sudo systemctl reboot," and that fixed the problem.

Comment: @kpdebree You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), as that comment to reboot the server could be helpful to others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a Bash shell. However, I got it to work, actually. I had to reboot the server to do it. Not exactly sure why. For future reference, I ran

```
sudo systemctl reboot
```

and that fixed the problem.